# angularJS bind async data to ng-repeat orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Sorry if I'm getting the terminology wrong.

I'm trying to have a list of movies with dates show in a list that can be ordered by either property. I can do this when working with a local JSON file and `$http` but as soon as I move to a async implementation the binding fails.

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/nelora/3/edit

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The orderByPriority filter is provided by AngularFire to convert an object returned by $firebase into an array. The objects in the array are ordered by priority (as defined in Firebase). Additionally, each object in the array will have a $id property defined on it, which will correspond to the key name for that object.

The key here is that it converts it to an array - which you can then run through your own filter to order it, as Firebase returns objects, not arrays.

```
<li ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderByPriority | orderBy:orderProp">
      {{movie.year}}—{{movie.title}}
 </li>
```

https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#orderbypriority